# Apache2 file uploads

Tags: apache-http-server, ftp

I have created a webserver at mwittam.co.uk, and I have put my server on the router's DMZ list but I cannot access it outside of my home network, and I would like to know how to upload files to the server from anywhere, from within an HTML document. eg:
    http://www.mwittam.co.uk/p/a/s/s/w/o/r/d/FTPUpload.html
Anyone know how?

Comment: What is mwittam.co.uk? Your dynamic DNS? Is your apache listening on all interfaces/addresses? Is your local firewall on the machine allowing FTP?

Comment: [mwittam.co.uk](mwittam.co.uk) is a permanant DNS redirect to the IP of my webserver, apache is listening on every port and every type of connection, I have no firewall

Comment: It's BAD practice not to have a firewall and a bit hard to believe. Are you sure? Could you reveal your OS and edit your question with the output of `netstat -anutp | grep :80` (I assume apache is listening on 80 and that it is a linux box) and the output where we can see that your firewall is disabled. I would suggest that you start your firewall and allow only port 80 to get through.